# Can a playable ad be uploaded from an external link?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Facebook Graph API allows for uploading ad videos from an external link, e.g. `https://example.con/videos/my_video.mp4` by `POST`ing to the `https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/$ACCOUNT_ID/advideos` with argument `file_url=https://example.con/videos/my_video.mp4`.
I haven't found anything similar for playable ads, and my application, that receives such an URL, currently needs to download the file and upload it locally.

I don't think there's any documented way, at least I was unable to find anything in the official documentation, and the fact playables are missing from the reference main page doesn't help. However, maybe someone found one, or worked it out with Facebook support or the like.

In any case, care to share?

EDIT: this would be very useful mostly to be able to do bulk requests; in the current scenario it's either impossible (it's likely to exceed the allowed request size) or harder than desirable (need to either download to temporary files instead of memory, keep track of the files, etc). I assume (may be wrong) that in principle bulk requests are accepted for this API, too.

Comment: You are likely to attract more help if you add more tags related to your problem :)

Comment: Thanks. I can't think of another relevant tag, tho, it's very specific to that API.

Comment: If ever I get into web development, I'll try to help you with this :P